# What parts of a Blob do I need to store in my database to retrieve back files?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am now able to store files in buckets:

```java
Blob blob = storage.create(
                BlobInfo.newBuilder(
                        BUCKET_NAME,
                        Objects.requireNonNull(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()))
                        .build(),
                multipartFile.getBytes()
        );
```

but I am not sure what I am supposed to keep in my own database in order to be able to retrieve my files back.

Now, the naive approach would be to just store a URL in a `google_bucket_url` column.

However, there's already the `mediaLink` and the `selfLink` - both of which look like they might not be valid forever.

I could also store the bucket plus the blob id

```java
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

// Blob blob = storage.create( .. );

BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(blob.getBucket(), blob.getName());
storage.get(blobId);
```

but instead of guessing what's the "*right*" way, I would like to be sure what I am doing.

I must be missing it in the docs but I can't find any recommendations on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to store the full URI of your blobs `gs://bucket_name/path/to/file`. **The full URI is important**. Tomorrow you will maybe have to store file on AWS S3 or locally, you have to identify the protocol to use for retrieving the file content.

When you have your full GCS URI `gs://bucket_name/path/to/file`, the split is easy for getting the file

```golang
// One line to split only at the first "/" character encounter and, previously, to replace the "gs://" by nothing
s := strings.SplitN(strings.Replace(URI, "gs://", ""), "/", 1)

// Then you can use this
bucketName := s[0]
pathToFile := s[1]
```

*Note: This code (here in Go) is easily implementable in any language*